# Constructor injection with @EJB(beanName = "myBean")

Tags: java, dependency-injection, ejb

is this possible ?
I want to do this :

```
@EJB(beanName = "MyStratImpl")
public DateTimeReadImpl(MyStrategy<MyBean> myStrategy) {
  this.strategy = myStrategy;
}
```

I have an no args constructor, I want to use constructor injection instead of doing field injection :

```
@EJB(beanName = "MyStratImpl")
private MyStrategy<MyBean> myStrategy strategy;
```

How do I use an ejb reference as a constructor parameter ?

(I can use setter injection, or reflection to inject, but I'd rather not)

Answer (score 3):

I don't think EJB supports constructor injection, but you can use [CDI](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/giwhl.html):

```
@Inject
public DateTimeReadImpl(MyStrategy<MyBean> myStrategy) {
    this.strategy = myStrategy;
}
```

You'll need to [enable CDI](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjbnz.html) for this to work. Also if you have more than one bean implementing `MyStrategy<MyBean>`, you can use [qualifiers](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjbck.html).